# real symmetric matrix Rayleigh quotient with extra constraint

Tags: linear-algebra

Let:
$$A=\left[\matrix{1&-2&-1\\-2&1&1\\-1&1&4}\right]$$
Question: Find the range of $y^{T}Ay$ for the real vectors $y=\left(\matrix{y_{1}\\y_{2}\\y_{3}}\right)$ that satisfy $y^{T}y=1$ and $y_{1}-y_{2}-2y_{3}=0$.

My solution so far:

I know that if $y^{T}y=1$ was the only constraint, then the range of $y^{T}Ay$ is simply between the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $A$. However, I'm not sure how to include the extra constraint $y_{1}-y_{2}-2y_{3}=0$.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps you could write an expression for the min/max of  $y^TAy$ with two constraints and solve. The min/max would be the range

Comment: The matrix has 3 eigenvalues. Each of them corresponds to an eigenvector, these are linearly independent. Therefore, they form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3,$ say $(\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3).$

The vectors $(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3})$ satisfying $y_{1}-y_{2}-2y_{3}=0$ create a subspace and can be written as a combination  $$a\vec{v}_1+b\vec{v}_2+c\vec{v}_3.$$ Then use the eigenvalues and the first constraint (vectors with norm 1).